Can this water storage tank be removed without reconfiguring plumbing?
The tank in the pic holds water, but we don't understand why. Best guess is that it was supposed to be passive heating from the old wood stove. I just want the whole thing out but I'm not sure if we can just cap things or if all the plumbing needs to change. What do I even call this thing?


I have no idea what that tank is.  I've seen far worse bathrooms.  The tub is probably an old clawfoot that someone built a poorly constructed deck around.   Big question is ...do you have another bathroom to use while this one is renovated?

Nope, this is our only one. We dont mind going in the woods for a day or two (we own a lot of acreage), but i know that will get old quickly. Haha.

Acreage is nice and all, but the normal thing for a project like this is to rent a portapotty for the duration. Contracts usually involve regular servicing, and you could save a few bucks by doing that service less frequently (since one family is way lower than typical volume).

While you got an answer you apparently found satisfactory, your question violates this site's policy by asking about multiple separate issues in one post. It also contained a fair amount of irrelevant rant (now removed). Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Consider revising to ask just one clear, concise question.

FYI, none of this is a "nightmare" or out of the ordinary for an old home remodel. Extensive termites are a nightmare. A failing foundation is a nightmare. This is just how folks did things before standardization and when they weren't afraid to innovate. Set aside the melodrama and just work through it. In fact, it can be extremely satisfying to go from this to something well done and modern. Keep your photos.

The tank has a pressure relief valve which probably is a strong clue that it is heated more than just passively by being above a stove on another floor.  Keep looking!

Or (as an alternative to @AloysiusDefenestrate's suggestion) a proper old-fashioned outhouse as you've got woods.  In the city it meant spending a few nights at the in-laws' and trips out at lunchtime.  There are also camping options to buy.

@isherwood: I know it's multiple questions in one originally... but I'm not sure having the title focus on the water tank when the OP asks about a LOT more is that helpful, for anyone.

Does the pipe at the top ever feel hot?  Can you remove all the insulation and list every pipe, wire, or covered hole you see, and as far as possible where they go and when they get hotter or colder?

@jay613 I am, but the system you describe isn't the common sort (I've done a little work on them, and they didn't have a pressure-relief from the tank to the drain like this; there could have been something up in the loft off the pipework to the bathroom, but to outside rather than a drain).  (Aside from combi boilers) the common sort has a coil on the primary, heating a stored volume on the secondary, with both vented.

@MatthieuM., I'm less concerned about making this invalid question helpful (in its current state) than I am in prompting the OP to revise it to conform to site policy. It should be closed as it is. This isn't Reddit. Also, the original title wasn't helpful to anyone searching for specific help. At least now it's helpful in one sense.

There is a lot that goes into renovating a bathroom...A LOT!
The first thing to do is find out what that tank is. Ask some neighbors if they have one and what they did with it.
You also need to take measurements and make a drawing of the "footprint of the room.  A drawing will help you understand how much space you have and prevent the guessing games when you find a bargain and wonder if it will fit.
Plan on replacing a fixture with something the same or very close to the same size.  Got a 30 inch sink vanity?  Replace it with a 30 inch. You may be able to squeeze in a 32 inch or so. This is where the drawing come into play.
Most toilets are standard and made to fit a 12 inch wall offset. Standard tubs are made to fit into a 60 inch area, but there are some that are smaller and you can get larger ones. Make a list of what size you need and what you can get.
There isn't enough I can gather from the pics to know what framing you need. That will have to be asked in another question and with more pics, and measurements help too.
Flooring is another issue. How much you need depends on how big the space.  Can you put flooring over what you have?  Probably not, but maybe...not enough known to be of much help there. Also tile for the walls if you plan to go that way, and if so you need thinset and grout.
Plan for the things you don't think of.  Plumbing supplies like shutoff valves, some piping and maybe drain lines. Electric switches and outlets, new lighting maybe an exhaust fan.  Remember you will need a number of types of screws, some nails, caulk, spackling, cement board, paint. And possible trim like baseboard and door casing.  There are probably other things I'm forgetting myself.
Finally plan for the time needed to complete the room... then triple it. Nothing goes as quick and as well as we think it will.

Although this answer isn't focused on the tank, as the question seems to be now, just the "triple it" is enough to earn an up vote. See Hofstadter's law: It always takes longer than you expect, even when you take into account Hofstadter's Law.

The tank looks like a hot water tank. It works both as a hot water storage tank and as a heat transfer between the hot water coming from the boiler, and water used to shower. Just make sure this tank is not hooked up to your boiler before removing it, as then you might have to either buy a combi boiler or install a separate electric or gas water heater.
About the bathroom, the fact that you can get some materials for free should bear little on your decision to do this project. Materials to do a bathroom reno are cheap. What is expensive is the labor, and that is because it involves many skilled trades. A typical by-the-book bathroom remodel requires 2 visits by a plumber, 2 visits by an electrician, a framing carpenter, a tile person, a finish carpenter and a painter. And at least 3 building permits (framing, plumbing, electrical) and 5 visits by the local inspectors.
Now, this is not to discourage DIY, and it is certainly a doable DIY project, but if you have never done this and don't have the tools and expertise, it can take you at least a month. This being your only bathroom, maybe double that time, as you'd have to clean up and leave a functioning bathroom at the end of every day. Doable, but tricky.
But let's say you only want to make the bathroom functional. You can change the vanity and the toilet (1 day), and then remove the tub, fix the framing and install one of those prefab fiberglass tubs and surround (1 day), and then wait until you either gain the necessary experience to tackle the full reno project, or save enough money to hire a contractor.
